# How to use re.compile within a for loop to extract substring indices

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of data from which I need to extract the indices of some strings within that list:

```
str=['cat','monkey']

list=['a cat','a dog','a cow','a lot of monkeys']
```

I've been using `re.compile` to match (even partial match) individual elements of the str list to the list:

```
regex=re.compile(".*(monkey).*")
b=[m.group(0) for l in list for m in [regex.search(l)] if m]
>>> list.index(b[0])
3
```

However, when I try to iterate over the str list to find the indices of those elements, I obtain empty lists:

```
>>> for i in str:
...     regex=re.compile(".*(i).*")
...     b=[m.group(0) for l in list for m in [regex.search(l)] if m]
...     print(b)
... 
[]
[]
```

I imagine that the problem is with `regex=re.compile(".*(i).*")`, but I don't know how to pass the ith element as a string.

Any suggestion is very welcome, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to use string formatting.

```
for i in str:
    match_pattern = ".*({}).*".format(i)
    regex = re.compile(match_pattern)
    b = [m.group(0) for l in list for m in [regex.search(l)] if m]
    print(b)
```